# Grating read permissions to aws s3 object with private bucket using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I'm trying to create an aws private s3 bucket using terraform and store some files in it. I want the files to be accessible by everyone.
I've tryed using "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" with

```
 block_public_acls       = false
 block_public_policy     = false
 ignore_public_acls      = false
 restrict_public_buckets = false
```

and adding "aws_s3_bucket_acl" with acl set to "public-read" and tryed using access _control_policy.

I can't seem to find a way but i know i did something wrong somewhere. Here's my code

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3" {
   bucket = var.bucket_name
   tags = {
     Name = var.bucket_name
     Environment = "Dev"
   }
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "s3_ownership" {
   bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3.id
   rule {
     object_ownership = "BucketOwnerPreferred"
   }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "s3_public_access" {
    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3.id

    block_public_acls = false
    block_public_policy = false
    ignore_public_acls = false
    restrict_public_buckets = false
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "s3_acl" {
    depends_on = [
        aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls.s3_ownership,
        aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.s3_public_access,
    ]

    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3.id
    acl = "public-read"
  }
```

what should i do to solve it

Comment: Is there any bucket policy applied to the bucket? How are you uploading objects to the bucket?

Comment: What makes it a "private" bucket if you are making it accessible to everyone?

Comment: i'm using "aws_s3_object" resource from terraform. I removed the bucket policies because it didn't work for me

Comment: i want to make the object accessible to everyone for download or viewing. i don't mind having the whole bucket on public read either.

Comment: If the bucket is private, you need bucket policy.

Comment: and if its on public-read ?